# Horisontal spacing CSS menu LI

Tags: css, html-lists, spacing

I'm trying to get the boxes for each `<li>` tag to position next to each other without spaces, but as they are now, they have a big space between each box. How do I remove that?

HTML code:
    
    
        Menu

```
<div id="menucontainer">
    <ul id="menu">
        <li><a href="#">Option1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Option1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Option1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Option1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Option1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Option1</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

CSS code:

```
ul {
margin: 0px;
padding: 0;
}

#menu li {
display: inline;
list-style: none;
}
#menu li a {
margin: 0px;
padding: 5px 30px 5px 30px;
text-align: center;
font-family: "Lucida Grande", "Lucida Sans Unicode", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
font-size: 15px;
color: rgba(66,48,1,1);
border: 1px solid rgba(105,181,50,1);
background: rgba(122,199,67,1);
}
#menu li a:hover {
cursor: pointer;
background: rgba(178,232,139,1);
color: rgba(0,0,0,1);
}
#menu a:link, #menu a:visited {
color: rgba(255,255,255,1);
text-decoration: none;
}
#menu a:active {
color: rgba(250,191,12,1);
}
#menu a#current {
background: rgba(85,137,48,1);
}
```

Comment: A JsFiddle would be great for us to identify your problems. I'm guessing, try to put your `</li>` and next `<li>` side by side, like this `<li> .... </li><li> ..... </li>`

Comment: Like what @hurrtz explained, it's about removing the white-space.. IMHO, it's more like a bug, how the browser generate such list.. So, just keep this trick in mind .. ^^

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those gaps are white-space characters. You can see them when you go with your cursor over one of those gaps - it changes to a text-cursor.

You can avoid this by

1. write your list items in one line, thus avoiding white space
2. float your list items like so:

CSS:

```
#menu li {
    display: inline;
    list-style: none;
    float: left;
}
```

Comment: Btw: If you wonder why your list elements overlap: It is because you give inline elements (<a>) padding-top and padding-bottom. This will only work correctly if you also apply "display: inline-block".